# heroku db:pull does not work?

Tags: ruby, database, heroku, migration, taps

I get the following error message:

```
heroku db:pull --debug postgres://USERNAME:PASSWORD@localhost/test 
Loaded Taps v0.3.23
Warning: Data in the database 'postgres://USERNAME:PASSWORD@localhost/test' will be overwritten and will not be recoverable.
Receiving schema
Unable to fetch tables information from http://heroku:foo9dsfsdfsdb465ar@taps19.heroku.com. Please check the server log.
```

The command above does not produce any messages in the log that can be viewed using 'heroku logs'.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: 1. just do "heroku db:pull" ?, 2.look at your own log, 3. does the live database actually have a schema?

Comment: Then you will get: Loaded Taps v0.3.23
 !    Invalid database url

Comment: Is there anything in the server log?  Can you open a support ticket?

Comment: There is nothing in the server log, I just opened a support ticket.

Comment: did you ever get an answer to this from heroku?

Comment: This is what they said:

taps is somewhat unreliable. Since you're also using pg locally, I recommend you use pgbackups instead:
http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/pgbackups

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have a replacement for db:push/pull that will soon be released. See https://github.com/heroku/heroku-pg-extras/issues/42 if you want to try it out early.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use pgbackups instead of taps/db:pull

http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/pgbackups

Comment: I freaking love Sequel Pro. Do you have a comparable tool to use for PGSQL? That is the sole reason I continue to use the taps gem.

Comment: @rpearce check out Induction: http://inductionapp.com - It's a little buggy right now, but it's open source and I believe it's actively developed.

Answer (score 2):

I answered to similar problem here: 
[Unable to fetch tables information when running heroku db:pull](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12580982/unable-to-fetch-tables-information-when-running-heroku-dbpull)

I found some kind of work-around.
I have the same problem with my SHARED_DATABASE on heroku 
ruby 1.9.2 
gems:
pg (0.11.0)
heroku (2.32.4)
heroku-api (0.3.5)
taps (0.3.24)
heroku db:pull ended with:

Unable to fetch tables information from http://...@taps19.heroku.com. Please check the server log.

I switched to ruby 1.8.7 using rvm and heroku db:pull works fine.
Back again to ruby 1.9.2 to develop my application.

I hope this help someone until db:pull will be fixed with ruby 1.9.2.

Answer (score 0):

Was able to get it going by reverting back to ruby 1.9.3 and Rails 3.1.0.

Here are some instructions on how to do that with rvm:

```
$ rvm install 1.9.3
$ ruby -v
$ rvm use 1.9.3-p286
$ rvm gemset create rails310
$ rvm 1.9.3-p286@rails310
$ rails -v
$ gem install rails -v 3.1.0
$ rvm gemset list
$ heroku db:pull –app <yourapp>
$ gem install taps
$ gem install sqlite3
$ heroku db:pull –app <yourapp>
```

More reading on rvm can be found here: http://rvm.io/gemsets/basics