# Unable to fetch tables information when running heroku db:pull

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, heroku, pull

I have an application that uses postgres in development and production. I recently pushed to heroku and everything was working fine. I was able to pull the database from heroku and push back up with no problem. Today however, I tried to pull the DB down from heroku and I received this error

```
heroku db:pull

Loaded Taps v0.3.24
    Auto-detected local database: postgres://postgres:a@127.0.0.1/app_development?encoding=utf8
    Warning: Data in the database 'postgres://postgres:a@127.0.0.1/app_development?encoding=utf8' will be overwritten and will not be recoverable.

     !    WARNING: Destructive Action
     !    This command will affect the app: app
     !    To proceed, type "app" or re-run this command with --confirm app

    > app
Receiving schema
Unable to fetch tables information from http://heroku:osui59a24am79x@taps19.heroku.com. Please check the server log.
```

So I run `heroku logs` after:

```
james@james-Vostro-3550:~/Desktop/app$ heroku logs
2012-09-25T10:08:32+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/users" for X.X.X.X at 2012-09-25 10:08:32 +0000
2012-09-25T10:08:32+00:00 heroku[router]: GET app.herokuapp.com/users? dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=38ms status=200 bytes=10727
2012-09-25T10:08:32+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-09-25T10:08:32+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-09-25T10:08:32+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/application.css" for X.X.X.X at 2012-09-25 10:08:32 +0000
2012-09-25T10:08:32+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-09-25T10:08:32+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
2012-09-25T10:08:32+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/application.css"):
2012-09-25T10:08:32+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
2012-09-25T10:08:32+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call_app'
2012-09-25T10:08:32+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
2012-09-25T10:08:32+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
2012-09-25T10:08:32+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
2012-09-25T10:08:32+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
2012-09-25T10:08:32+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
2012-09-25T10:08:32+00:00 heroku[router]: GET app.herokuapp.com/application.css dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=6ms status=404 bytes=728
2012-09-25T10:08:32+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
2012-09-25T10:08:32+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:62:in `call'
2012-09-25T10:08:32+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:136:in `forward'
2012-09-25T10:08:32+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:245:in `fetch'
2012-09-25T10:08:32+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:185:in `lookup'
2012-09-25T10:08:32+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:66:in `call!'
2012-09-25T10:08:32+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:51:in `call'
2012-09-25T10:08:32+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
2012-09-25T10:08:32+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/application.rb:220:in `call'
2012-09-25T10:08:32+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
2012-09-25T10:08:32+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.4.1/lib/thin/connection.rb:78:in `catch'
2012-09-25T10:08:32+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.4.1/lib/thin/connection.rb:80:in `block in pre_process'
2012-09-25T10:08:32+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.4.1/lib/thin/connection.rb:53:in `process'
2012-09-25T10:08:32+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.4.1/lib/thin/connection.rb:78:in `pre_process'
2012-09-25T10:08:32+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.4.1/lib/thin/connection.rb:38:in `receive_data'
2012-09-25T10:08:32+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/eventmachine-0.12.10/lib/eventmachine.rb:256:in `run_machine'
2012-09-25T10:08:32+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/eventmachine-0.12.10/lib/eventmachine.rb:256:in `run'
2012-09-25T10:08:32+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.4.1/lib/thin/backends/base.rb:63:in `start'
2012-09-25T10:08:32+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.4.1/lib/thin/server.rb:159:in `start'
2012-09-25T10:08:32+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.4.1/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:86:in `start'
2012-09-25T10:08:32+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.4.1/lib/thin/runner.rb:185:in `run_command'
2012-09-25T10:08:32+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.4.1/lib/thin/runner.rb:151:in `run!'
2012-09-25T10:08:32+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.4.1/bin/thin:6:in `<top (required)>'
2012-09-25T10:08:32+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/thin:19:in `load'
2012-09-25T10:08:32+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/thin:19:in `<main>'
2012-09-25T10:08:32+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-09-25T10:08:32+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-09-25T10:08:32+00:00 heroku[router]: GET app.herokuapp.com/assets/admin-e0756c8b3550bb800d5f58837c42ec80.css dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=7ms status=200 bytes=1941
2012-09-25T10:08:32+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-09-25T10:08:32+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-09-25T10:08:32+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/assets/admin-e0756c8b3550bb800d5f58837c42ec80.css" for X.X.X.X at 2012-09-25 10:08:32 +0000
2012-09-25T10:08:41+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-09-25T10:08:41+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-09-25T10:08:41+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/projects" for X.X.X.X at 2012-09-25 10:08:41 +0000
2012-09-25T10:08:41+00:00 heroku[router]: GET app.herokuapp.com/projects dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=31ms status=304 bytes=0
2012-09-25T10:08:41+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/application.css" for X.X.X.X at 2012-09-25 10:08:41 +0000
2012-09-25T10:08:41+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-09-25T10:08:41+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-09-25T10:08:41+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
2012-09-25T10:08
:41+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
2012-09-25T10:08:41+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
2012-09-25T10:08:41+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-09-25T10:08:41+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
2012-09-25T10:08:41+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/application.css"):
2012-09-25T10:08:41+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:185:in `lookup'
2012-09-25T10:08:41+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
2012-09-25T10:08:41+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:51:in `call'
2012-09-25T10:08:41+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call_app'
2012-09-25T10:08:41+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:245:in `fetch'
2012-09-25T10:08:41+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
2012-09-25T10:08:41+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
2012-09-25T10:08:41+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
2012-09-25T10:08:41+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
2012-09-25T10:08:41+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:62:in `call'
2012-09-25T10:08:41+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:136:in `forward'
2012-09-25T10:08:41+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/application.rb:220:in `call'
2012-09-25T10:08:41+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.4.1/lib/thin/server.rb:159:in `start'
2012-09-25T10:08:41+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.4.1/lib/thin/connection.rb:78:in `catch'
2012-09-25T10:08:41+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
2012-09-25T10:08:41+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/eventmachine-0.12.10/lib/eventmachine.rb:256:in `run_machine'
2012-09-25T10:08:41+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:66:in `call!'
2012-09-25T10:08:41+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.4.1/lib/thin/connection.rb:80:in `block in pre_process'
2012-09-25T10:08:41+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.4.1/lib/thin/connection.rb:53:in `process'
2012-09-25T10:08:41+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.4.1/lib/thin/backends/base.rb:63:in `start'
2012-09-25T10:08:41+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.4.1/lib/thin/connection.rb:78:in `pre_process'
2012-09-25T10:08:41+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/eventmachine-0.12.10/lib/eventmachine.rb:256:in `run'
2012-09-25T10:08:41+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.4.1/lib/thin/connection.rb:38:in `receive_data'
2012-09-25T10:08:41+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.4.1/lib/thin/runner.rb:151:in `run!'
2012-09-25T10:08:41+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.4.1/lib/thin/runner.rb:185:in `run_command'
2012-09-25T10:08:41+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-09-25T10:08:41+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/thin:19:in `<main>'
2012-09-25T10:08:41+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.4.1/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:86:in `start'
2012-09-25T10:08:41+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.4.1/bin/thin:6:in `<top (required)>'
2012-09-25T10:08:41+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/thin:19:in `load'
2012-09-25T10:08:41+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-09-25T10:08:41+00:00 heroku[router]: GET app.herokuapp.com/application.css dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=9ms status=404 bytes=728
2012-09-25T10:11:00+00:00 heroku[run.1]: Awaiting client
2012-09-25T10:11:00+00:00 heroku[run.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate`
2012-09-25T10:11:00+00:00 heroku[run.1]: State changed from starting to up
2012-09-25T10:11:06+00:00 heroku[run.1]: Client connection closed. Sending SIGHUP to all processes
2012-09-25T10:11:07+00:00 heroku[run.1]: Process exited with status 1
2012-09-25T10:11:07+00:00 heroku[run.1]: State changed from up to complete
2012-09-25T10:08:23+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2012-09-25T10:08:01+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Unidling
2012-09-25T10:08:01+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to starting
```

I have no idea where to look for a solution, so hopefully someone can help. I've just started learning rails so please remember this when trying to help.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

I have tried all sorts: 
reinstalling heroku, taps.
remade my app and pushing to heroku.
reinstalled postgres.

Nothing seems to work. Driving me mad!

Comment: Have you retried it to see if it is reproducible error? I sometimes get failures on db:push and pull, but very rarely, and it is usually gone on retry, seeming to be a short time server instability.

Comment: Error in logs is not related to DB, it says it cannot find application.css, probably some problem with the asset pipeline.

Comment: I have retried it a few times and get the same error. Site still works online but I can't pull the database. The log doesn't seem to show that there has been a DB pull attempt.

Comment: I have the exact same issue this morning. Nothing to see in my logs. Maybe an issue at heroku?

Comment: Hm, I can find plenty of mentions of this error in google, but there is no real solution anywhere.

Comment: @ndemoreau did you manage to fix the issue at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found some kind of work-around.
I have the same problem with my SHARED_DATABASE on heroku 
ruby 1.9.2 
gems:
pg (0.11.0)
heroku (2.32.4)
heroku-api (0.3.5)
taps (0.3.24)
heroku db:pull ended with:

Unable to fetch tables information from http://...@taps19.heroku.com. Please check the server log.

I switched to ruby 1.8.7 using rvm and heroku db:pull works fine.
Back again to ruby 1.9.2 to develop my application.

I hope this help someone until db:pull will be fixed with ruby 1.9.2.

Comment: Works for me too. Thank you! I will still leave this question unanswered till there is a solution for ruby 1.9.2

Comment: Using 1.9.3-p194, taps just quit working out of the blue. I continue to use MySQL locally because of how easy Sequel Pro is instead of using pgbackups. This answer worked for me. Thanks <3

Answer (score 2):

## MySQL

(Instructions for PostgreSQL are further down the page)

A temporary workaround would be to directly dump the data from your DB server and load it manually yourself. I have both databases (on Heroku and locally) in MySQL, so I did:

```sh
1. mysqldump -h host -P port_number -u user_name_to_your_db -p your_db_name > data.sql
```

Once you run the above command with correct details you will be asked to enter your password.

**NOTE**: Never put your password into your shell command as it is being stored in shell commands history.

Get your `username`, `password`, `your_db_name`, `host` and `port_number` from Heroku config:

```sh
2. heroku config --app your-app-name | grep DATABASE_URL
```

Your `DATABASE_URL` will look like this:

```sh
mysql2://username:password@host:port_number/your_db_name
```

An example of a bit more real `DATABASE_URL` will look like this (the login details there are modified):

```sh
mysql2://afdgsdfghliue:ESIJAFDG-sAFsgiags3464@ec2-34-15-23-232.compute-2.amazonaws.com:5432/9twgsenr8543
```

In that case the details would be respectively (remember, these are fake ones):

```sh
username: afdgsdfghliue:ESIJAFDG
password: ESIJAFDG-sAFsgiags3464
host:     ec2-34-15-23-232.compute-2.amazonaws.com
port:     5432
database: 9twgsenr8543
```

When you run the `mysqldump` with correct details as shown in `1.` you will have your data stored in data.sql locally. Now to load it to your local database (we are still talking about MySQL) you will need to run:

```sh
mysql -u your_local_db_username -h 127.0.0.1 -p your_local_db_name < data.sql
```

The local database login details you should have.

## PostgreSQL

I haven't checked the below instructions myself, so please use them together with your brain ;-)

I found from

```sh
pg_dump --help
```

that you could run similar commands to dump your PostgreSQL database from Heroku like this:

```sh
pg_dump -h host -p port -U username -W your_db_name > data.sql
```

Your `DATABASE_URL` will start with `postgres`:

```sh
postgres://username:password@host:port_number/your_db_name
```

Based on

```sh
psql --help
```

here is how to load your local PostgreSQL database from the `data.sql` file prepared above:

```sh
psql -h 127.0.0.1 -U your_local_db_username -W -d your_local_db_name -f data.sql
```

A bit of manual process, but it at least gets you going.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, and I had a bit of trouble. Not going to go into it as I just want to get `heroku db:pull` working again

Comment: I also want to `heroku db:pull` to work again. I submitted a ticket on http://help.heroku.com so maybe they will do something about it. But for now the above solution allowed me to move on with my work.

Answer (score 2):

I just received an answer from heroku. They said that they were having some issues with taps and that it is working again now.

I checked and I confirm that it's working for me.

Rgds,