# heroku db:pull results in TypeError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

When running `heroku db:pull`, I immediately see this error:

```
Failed to connect to database:
  Sequel::DatabaseConnectionError -> TypeError: wrong argument type nil (expected Hash)
```

Even adding the `--debug` flag doesn't show anything extra.

- heroku heroku-toolbelt/2.35.0 (x86_64-darwin10.8.0) ruby/1.9.3
- taps 0.3.24
- ruby 2.0.0-p0
- rails 4.0.0.beta1

Comment: does this help? https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/9491

Comment: Don't use db:pull. Use pgbackups http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8892354/heroku-dbpull-does-not-work

Answer (score 0):

Is your development DB correctly setup? e.g. can you start `rails console` and run a query?

Comment: Yes. You can post a comment next time for clarification.